# Problem in using Provider in flutter when listen:true

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, provider

I'm working on an app in Flutter. I try to use Provider in the app but have faced this error:

```
Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.
E/flutter ( 2850): 
E/flutter ( 2850): This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
E/flutter ( 2850): Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.
E/flutter ( 2850): 
E/flutter ( 2850): To fix, write:
E/flutter ( 2850): Provider.of<Complexes>(context, listen: false);
E/flutter ( 2850): 
E/flutter ( 2850): It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget associated to the
E/flutter ( 2850): event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care about the value.
```

My code is :

```dart
loadedComplexes = Provider.of<Complexes>(context, listen: true).favoriteItems;
```

When is set to `listen:false`, the problem solved. but I think this is not a good way to solve this problem. Also, I need provider to listen. I have searched the internet but could not find any suitable solution.

This is my Flutter Doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.657],    locale en-US)
   • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.7 at C:\android\flutter
   • Framework revision 9f5ff2306b (6 weeks ago), 2020-01-26 22:38:26 -0800
   • Engine revision a67792536c
   • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:/android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:/android/sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.4
    • Dart plugin version 193.5731

[!] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Altay\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 5.0.2 (API 21) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

My provider block:

```dart
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => Salons(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => Cities(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => Auth(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => Complexes(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => UserInfo(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => User(),
    ),
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(........
```

The method which call the provider:

```dart
Future<void> _submit() async {
    loadedComplexes.clear();
    loadedComplexes =
        Provider.of<Complexes>(context, listen: true).favoriteItems;
    loadedComplexestolist.addAll(loadedComplexes);
}
```

I can provide more information if it's necessary. Is there any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please share where exactly you define your BlocProvider and when exactly you call the BlocProvider.of(context) so that we can help you easily. Also check out the sample app from Provider package for detailed reference.

Comment: @Darish I updated the question and add the provider block

Answer (score 8):

The error clearly says your declaring it out side of the `Widget` tree.
If you want to set `listen` to true then you must declare it inside the `Widget` tree so that the provider knows which `Widget` tree has to be rebuilt when changes occur.

**Example**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 loadedComplexes = Provider.of<Complexes>(context, listen: true).favoriteItems;//You must declare here if listen to true
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
 );
```

}
}

Setting `listen` to `true` makes the whole widget as a listener and leads to rebuilding the whole widget tree. But setting listen to `false` will help you to rebuild a particular widget which you declared as a `Consumer` (a consumer is a widget which listen for changes).

[check this video mate. He uses the same approach as you did](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QT2LFIe794I)

Comment: Consumer rebuild even if listen false? Does the consumer expensive compared to the provider.? Please explain . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If `listen` should ways be `true`, provider wouldn't have this flag.

The situation you are in requires `listen:false` for a reason. It is the correct solution here.

Comment: Hi Rémi Rousselet, is it possible to add event handler inside of consumer, which will be separated from build method. For example, on processing finished I wan't to open another screen, how to handle it?

Answer (score 3):

I just changed that

**Provider.of(context);**

to

**context.watch();**

**Note**: Provider can listen only on build() and didChangeDependencies() methods.
In initState() method doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed

```
Provider.of<YourProvider>(context);
```

to

```
Provider.of<YourProvider>(context,listen: false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting listen to false is not bad practice. It is used when accessing a provider value once, or calling a provider method.

If you want to listen to updates, you have the choice between [a number of different providers](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#existing-providers).

Answer (score 0):

Replace this snippet of your code

```
create: (ctx) =>
```

whith

```
create: (ctx, listen: false) =>
```